# iOS: How to execute functionn in other task without lagg

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sdwebimage

I have a problem. I have a UITableViewCell with images. The images are dynamically loaded from the application bundle. The function is about 200 lines with a lot of if satements in it. I basically extract the icon of the file acording to the suffix of the file, if the file is an Application I parse the info.plist and extract the filename of the icon. if the filename in the plist has no suffix I append it and then I chose the biggest icon. The function then returns the fileURL of the file either in my app bundle or in the app bundle of the app I parsed. I also do more stuff, but thats to complicated to explain.

I am already using `SDWebImage`, thats why I return a `NSURL` and not the `UIImage`.

The problem is, that the scrolling is lagging very hard on older devices without the A7 CPU.
My thought is that I put the function in another `NSOperationQueue`, but I am not quite sure because I am already using the `SDWebImage` with `compblock`. The images dont have to be loaded instant, it can take some, meanwhile I display a placeholder image.

Does anyone have an idea how I can make this fluid?

Thanks, David

**I just fixed my issue, I executed my own NSUserDefault with costume en- and decryption multiple times in on function! I fixed it by minimizing it and calling it once and store the value. Thanks for all your help!**

Comment: `SDWebImage` is really meant to work for URL of web resource, since it relies heavily on http caching. You should write your own image loader and not use `SDWebImage`. IN this loader you can use `NSCache` to speed up the loading of images. Also have a look at this: https://github.com/path/FastImageCache

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

This sample may help you:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

The general rule is: the main thread is just for changing your UI. Other works should be done in another thread. Try to move your code to a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

are you parsing the plist file each time a table view cell is displayed? if yes => parse the plist file only once, save the result somewhere in memory, and use that instead. this is "lazy/cached loading". an `NSDictionary` is probably a good choice for this. keys are the keys that you are using to decide which image to display. and the values should be `NSURL` objects.

This should make the whole process much faster.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer, I am just implementing a caching function. on the first TableViewLoad all paths of the loaded images are saved in a .plist in /Library/Caches/iconCache.plist. The key is the application name and the object is the image path, so it should be faster too. In addition I am thinking of using SVG files instead of PNG files, so I dont need to load the .png files, but then I need to draw the SVG file everytime, do you think this is quicker?

Comment: @DavidG. caching into a file is almost always a bad idea. I was once able to improve performance by just disabling the file-cache, because you can waste many CPU-cycles before going to the hard disk becomes a performance improvement! It can be really counter-intuitive sometimes... if the plist-file is just a cache, have you tried not saving it to a file but keeping the structure it represents in memory and keeping it there? BTW, you don't save RAM-space by saving the data to a file...

Comment: @DavidG. as for PNG vs. SVG... i really have no idea which format can be loaded faster. you'd just have to measure this. But I think the performance bottleneck is somewhere else, because in one app of mine I have a different image (in PNG format) in each table view cell, and they are all loaded from the app-bundle, with an ordinary `UIImageView` and `-[UIImage imageNamed:]`, and it runs smooth on an iPhone3GS with iOS 6...

Comment: I just fixed my issue, I executed my own NSUserDefault with costume en- and decryption multiple times in on function! I fixed it by minimizing it and calling it once and store the value. Thanks for all your help!